# Traefik is ignoring docker with traefik.enable=true set

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, traefik

#### What did you expect to see?

I Expected to see a new front-end and back-end when I `docker-compose up` my wordpress stack.

#### What did you see instead?

No new front or back ends. 2 Log lines = `level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker"`

Also seeing `"Filtering disabled container /testEXAMPLEcom_wordpress_1"` even though `traefik.enable=true` is set in the labels.

#### Output of `traefik version`:

```
Traefik version v1.7.11 built on 2019-04-26_08:42:33AM
```

#### What is your environment & configuration?

```
cat traefik.toml
#debug = true

logLevel = "INFO" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend and backend configurations
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [entryPoints.https.redirect]
        permanent=true
        regex = "^https://www.(.*)"
        replacement = "https://$1"

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

# Let's encrypt configuration
[acme]
email = "japayton42@gmail.com" #any email id will work
storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
onHostRule = true
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 3
```

```
cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3.6"
services:

  traefik:
    hostname: traefik
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    domainname: ${DOMAINNAME}
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=${CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL}
      - CF_API_KEY=${CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=0"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=host.EXAMPLE.com"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=${HTTP_USERNAME}:${HTTP_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - ${USERDIR}/shared:/shared


networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external:
      name: traefik_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

```
cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
    networks:
      - db
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    labels:
      - "traefik.enabled=true"
      - "traefik.domain=test.EXAMPLE.com"
      - "traefik.backend=test.EXAMPLE.com"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.test.EXAMPLE.com,test.EXAMPLE.com"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=0"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=EXAMPLE.com"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=false"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny=true"
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
      - db
networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
  db:
    external: false
```

#### If applicable, please paste the log output in DEBUG level

```
Attaching to traefik
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:34Z" level=info msg="Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:34Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.7.11 built on 2019-04-26_08:42:33AM"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:34Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {\"LifeCycle\":{\"RequestAcceptGraceTimeout\":0,\"GraceTimeOut\":10000000000},\"GraceTimeOut\":0,\"Debug\":false,\"CheckNewVersion\":true,\"SendAnonymousUsage\":false,\"AccessLogsFile\":\"\",\"AccessLog\":null,\"TraefikLogsFile\":\"\",\"TraefikLog\":null,\"Tracing\":null,\"LogLevel\":\"DEBUG\",\"EntryPoints\":{\"http\":{\"Address\":\":80\",\"TLS\":null,\"Redirect\":{\"entryPoint\":\"https\"},\"Auth\":null,\"WhitelistSourceRange\":null,\"WhiteList\":null,\"Compress\":false,\"ProxyProtocol\":null,\"ForwardedHeaders\":{\"Insecure\":true,\"TrustedIPs\":null}},\"https\":{\"Address\":\":443\",\"TLS\":{\"MinVersion\":\"\",\"CipherSuites\":null,\"Certificates\":null,\"ClientCAFiles\":null,\"ClientCA\":{\"Files\":null,\"Optional\":false},\"DefaultCertificate\":null,\"SniStrict\":false},\"Redirect\":{\"regex\":\"^https://www.(.*)\",\"replacement\":\"https://$1\",\"permanent\":true},\"Auth\":null,\"WhitelistSourceRange\":null,\"WhiteList\":null,\"Compress\":false,\"ProxyProtocol\":null,\"ForwardedHeaders\":{\"Insecure\":true,\"TrustedIPs\":null}},\"traefik\":{\"Address\":\":8080\",\"TLS\":null,\"Redirect\":null,\"Auth\":null,\"WhitelistSourceRange\":null,\"WhiteList\":null,\"Compress\":false,\"ProxyProtocol\":null,\"ForwardedHeaders\":{\"Insecure\":true,\"TrustedIPs\":null}}},\"Cluster\":null,\"Constraints\":[],\"ACME\":{\"Email\":\"EXAMPLE@gmail.com\",\"Domains\":null,\"Storage\":\"/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json\",\"StorageFile\":\"\",\"OnDemand\":false,\"OnHostRule\":true,\"CAServer\":\"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"EntryPoint\":\"https\",\"KeyType\":\"\",\"DNSChallenge\":{\"Provider\":\"cloudflare\",\"DelayBeforeCheck\":3000000000,\"Resolvers\":null,\"DisablePropagationCheck\":false},\"HTTPChallenge\":null,\"TLSChallenge\":null,\"DNSProvider\":\"\",\"DelayDontCheckDNS\":0,\"ACMELogging\":true,\"OverrideCertificates\":false,\"TLSConfig\":null},\"DefaultEntryPoints\":[\"https\",\"http\"],\"ProvidersThrottleDuration\":2000000000,\"MaxIdleConnsPerHost\":200,\"IdleTimeout\":0,\"InsecureSkipVerify\":true,\"RootCAs\":null,\"Retry\":{\"Attempts\":0},\"HealthCheck\":{\"Interval\":30000000000},\"RespondingTimeouts\":null,\"ForwardingTimeouts\":null,\"AllowMinWeightZero\":false,\"KeepTrailingSlash\":false,\"Web\":null,\"Docker\":{\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":false,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false,\"Network\":\"\",\"SwarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15},\"File\":null,\"Marathon\":null,\"Consul\":null,\"ConsulCatalog\":null,\"Etcd\":null,\"Zookeeper\":null,\"Boltdb\":null,\"Kubernetes\":null,\"Mesos\":null,\"Eureka\":null,\"ECS\":null,\"Rancher\":null,\"DynamoDB\":null,\"ServiceFabric\":null,\"Rest\":null,\"API\":{\"EntryPoint\":\"traefik\",\"Dashboard\":true,\"Debug\":false,\"CurrentConfigurations\":null,\"Statistics\":null},\"Metrics\":null,\"Ping\":null,\"HostResolver\":null}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:34Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#collected-data\n"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:34Z" level=debug msg="Setting Acme Certificate store from Entrypoint: https"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Preparing server traefik &{Address::8080 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc000376be0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Creating entry point redirect http -> https"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Creating regex redirect https -> ^https://www.(.*) -> https://$1"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:0xc00019b500 Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc000376c00} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Creating entry point redirect http -> https"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Creating regex redirect https -> ^https://www.(.*) -> https://$1"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Address::443 TLS:0xc00042aab0 Redirect:0xc00019b680 Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc000376ba0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :8080"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Starting provider configuration.ProviderAggregator {}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":false,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false,\"Network\":\"\",\"SwarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.Provider {\"Email\":\"EXAMPLE@gmail.com\",\"ACMELogging\":true,\"CAServer\":\"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"Storage\":\"/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json\",\"EntryPoint\":\"https\",\"KeyType\":\"\",\"OnHostRule\":true,\"OnDemand\":false,\"DNSChallenge\":{\"Provider\":\"cloudflare\",\"DelayBeforeCheck\":3000000000,\"Resolvers\":null,\"DisablePropagationCheck\":false},\"HTTPChallenge\":null,\"TLSChallenge\":null,\"Domains\":null,\"Store\":{}}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Testing certificate renew..."
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider ACME: {}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 18.09.5 (API 1.39)"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container /traefik"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) host.EXAMPLE.com"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :443"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :8080"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) host.EXAMPLE.com"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :8080"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:35Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :443"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:49Z" level=debug msg="Provider event received {Status:start ID:58b2b12336a7488012b68fed21f90476a1e791f4aa17fff7bd266ee9dfbe7a68 From:mysql:latest Type:container Action:start Actor:{ID:58b2b12336a7488012b68fed21f90476a1e791f4aa17fff7bd266ee9dfbe7a68 Attributes:map[image:mysql:latest com.docker.compose.config-hash:f4e61702252003fcfa77f925b989f7ea4933faa6e0735d189d265eabcb5fa799 com.docker.compose.container-number:1 com.docker.compose.service:db com.docker.compose.version:1.24.0 name:testEXAMPLEcom_db_1 traefik.enable:false com.docker.compose.oneoff:False com.docker.compose.project:testEXAMPLEcom]} Scope:local Time:1556929789 TimeNano:1556929789841010516}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:49Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container /testEXAMPLEcom_db_1"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:49Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container /traefik"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:49Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:49Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:50Z" level=debug msg="Provider event received {Status:start ID:6d816029188e7a2ff7b7d37fec254e21424cb3e2f69b42c81638d40d56d818f3 From:wordpress:latest Type:container Action:start Actor:{ID:6d816029188e7a2ff7b7d37fec254e21424cb3e2f69b42c81638d40d56d818f3 Attributes:map[com.docker.compose.version:1.24.0 traefik.docker.network:traefik_proxy traefik.domain:test.EXAMPLE.com traefik.enabled:true traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost:EXAMPLE.com traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter:true com.docker.compose.container-number:1 traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload:false traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds:0 traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff:true traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader:false com.docker.compose.oneoff:False com.docker.compose.service:wordpress traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect:true traefik.frontend.rule:Host:www.test.EXAMPLE.com,test.EXAMPLE.com traefik.port:80 com.docker.compose.config-hash:3e163655e60a2111f256d3abc3289244f21676737888f7f4340cd543d82300d0 com.docker.compose.project:testEXAMPLEcom image:wordpress:latest name:testEXAMPLEcom_wordpress_1 traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains:false traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny:true]} Scope:local Time:1556929790 TimeNano:1556929790976253470}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:50Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container /testEXAMPLEcom_wordpress_1"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:50Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container /testEXAMPLEcom_db_1"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:50Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container /traefik"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:50Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {}"
traefik    | time="2019-05-04T00:29:50Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider docker"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was using `traefik.enabled` instead of `traefik.enable`

I tried for a week before posting,

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should accept your own answer as correct.